# Graph library or sdk in android

Tags: java, android, graph

I would like to know if there is a library or an sdk that lets me use mathematical graphs (nodes and edges) without having to implement my own one and for instance having a built in function for Dijkstra Algorythm.
If anybody knows if such thing exists it would be much appreciated to have a link to that.

Thanks anyone for the feedback.

Comment: Try searching "android ploting package". There are many you can look at.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found any libraries, but with some simple code adaptations [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaAlgorithmsDijkstra/article.html) solved my issue and I managed to implement my own graph and graph management, with Djikstra algorithm implementation as well.
Maybe someone else will find this usefull.